# Script prevents page from refreshing

Tags: javascript, php

I've created a script which in essence runs a PHP script for me externally and brings back the results to me. The problem with this script is that it takes around 20 seconds to complete and while this script is running the page refuses to refresh.

What is a good Javascript practice to counteract this?

For reference (script):

`$.post('/api/myob/synchronise', {
            _token: token,
            task_id: task_id
});`

Comment: Has the PHP been fully optimised, 20 seconds is a long execution time? Does the page need to refresh if the PHP has not finished its job yet?

Comment: Over 10000 database entries and those are processed as neccessary hahaha

Comment: The page refreshing is more of a user experience functionality. The script can reset at any point. I'm just trying to understand why the script freezes reloads but doesn't freeze the page etc

Comment: PHP is a preprocessor, so it would normally be used to process first, you are trying to use it in parallel with javascript?

Comment: To be fair running it initially would result in the page taking a long time to load hence why I'm doing it while the page has loaded. In essence it is a synchronising task. Is there a way I can do this before page loads while also rendering ui at same time? Otherwise I may result in cronjobbing it :)

Answer (score 0):

How about using jQuery to load the PHP page after the rest of the page has loaded?
It will run 1 second after the page has finished loading.
(This script requires jquery to be [downloaded](https://jquery.com/))

```
<div id="some_id"></div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>          
<script type="text/javascript">

// Check if the page has loaded completely                                         
$(document).ready( function() { 
    setTimeout( function() { 
        $('#some_id').load('index.php'); 
    }, 1000); 
}); 
</script>
```

Comment: Please note this is not a UI update but is a database operation. Moreover parameters are to be passed to the script (i guess get parameters are possible in this scenario)

Comment: Yes, you could always use `.load('index.php?One=Var)` etc. to send variables with GET.  It would be the best solution and not involve loading times.

Comment: @OliverKuchies - Are you happy with the answer?